# How to avoid adding same item/product/row to a Datatable

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, datatable

As showing this image below I use a Datatable to list out products and quantity details entered by user.

[image: table]

But I want to restrict adding the same item more than one time. I use Ajax to get data from the database and Datatable draw() method to make the above table. As it shows there are two records with the same MAterial ID or Name. How can I avoid this problem?

```
  mat_req_table.row.add( {
 "mat_id": response.id,
 "name":  response.name,
 "quantity":check,
 "action": '<button id="edit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button> <button id="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>',

 } ).draw();
```

This is the way I populate DataTable

```
$('#add').click(function(){
            if( $('#materialselect').val() != ''){
                var check = $('#quantity').val();
                var params = {
                    key1: $('#materialselect').val(),
                    key2: $('#quantity').val(),
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url: BASE + 'materialrequest/add',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: $.param(params),
                    success: function (response) {
                        var max =(response['high_bulk']);
                        if(check > max){
                            alert('amount you request can not be exceed total stock amount');
                            $('#quantity').val('');
                        }else{
                            mat_req_table.row.add( {

                                "mat_id": response.id,
                                "name":  response.name,
                                "quantity":check,
                                "action": '<button id="edit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></button> <button id="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>',

                            } ).draw();
                            $('#materialselect').val('');
                            $('#quantity').val('');
                        }


                    }
                });
                return false;
            }else{
                alert('please select material');
            }

        });
```

Server side

```
    public function add(Request $request)
{
    if($request->get('key2')){
        $key1 = $request->get('key1');
        $key2 = $request->get('key2');

        $material_name = $key1;
        $material = MaterialRegister::where('name',$material_name)->first();


        return response()->json(['name'=>$material->name,'id'=>$material->id,'high_bulk'=>$material->high_bulk]);

    }
}
```

Table declaration

```
            var mat_req_table = $('#materialrequesttable').DataTable( {

            searching:false,
            paging:false,
            "ordering":false,
            bInfo:false,
            data:[],
            columns: [

            {data: 'mat_id', name: 'mat_id'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'quantity', name: 'quantity'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action'},

            ]

        } );
```

Comment: how about a unique key on the id in the db, may want to do something client side alos

Comment: How do you actually populate the table in the first place? Code?

Comment: The object you pass into the add method should be abstracted out, make an array of items instead, you can then use the material id to match existing and update or add, *then* apply all the data to the table.

Comment: Whats the Update button do?

Comment: sidenote, delete or edit will only delete or edit the first row as your using id's and not a class

Comment: I'd say you should validate this on the server side. You're going to have to do that anyway when you handle the form submission. (I'm assuming; this looks like an order or inventory form.) Keep the item info in the session, validate in PHP, including uniqueness, and return an error in the AJAX response if someone tries to add a duplicate item.

Comment: can you also put your code in your add button?

Comment: i added some code segments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider a custom Request object, and list out the fields and rules you wish to validate against.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation

You could use existing validation rules for this. So, for example, to ensure unique Material IDs, given table ‘Material’:

```
function rules() {
  return [‘material_id’ => ‘exists:materials_table,id’];
}
```